# C#, DragDrop re-ordering algorithm

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a list of objects in C# that have a property called 'Sequence'.  This list is then bound to a DataGridView, ordering by this Sequence.

The user is able to drag and drop rows - so if we have something like the following:

```
Name,Sequence 
Test1,1 
Test2,2
Test3,3 
Test4,4 
Test5,5
```

Dragging 'Test1' to between 'Test3' and 'Test4' should modify the sequence of anything effected to be the following:

```
Name,Sequence 
Test2,1 
Test3,2
Test1,3 
Test4,4 
Test5,5
```

I can't quite figure out the algorithm to use to update the list when they drag and drop a row. A simple way would be to loop through all the rows in the grid and and update the sequence to be the row index + 1, but I think this will add some overhead.

Comment: after dropping just update the sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can avoid storing `Sequence` with the object, otherwise a possibility of it getting out of sequence will always remain. You can pair up an object with its sequence for downstream consumption when enumerating through the container:

```
class MyData {
    string Name {get; set;}
}
class DataWithSequence {
    MyData Data {get;set;}
    int Sequence{get;set;}
}
...
IList<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
IEnumerable<DataWithSequence> GetData() {
    return list.Select((d,i)=> new DataWithSequence {Data=d, Sequence=i+1});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> but I think this'll add some overhead.

Very, very little.

And it has the benefit of not requiring any magic.